# Como faço para abrir uma aba do google maps no unity sem comprar um Asset?

Tags: google-maps, unity-5

Estou com dificuldade em descobrir como que faço para abrir uma aba ou o próprio app do google maps no meu app dentro do unity, e não tenho como comprar o Asset para facilitar, o que eu faço? tem algum outro site ou aplicativo que eu possa usar e seja mais fácil?